# Prevent OSX Download Notification When Testing PDF Download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

We're using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) to render a PDF in our Rails app. I'm trying to write tests for it.

controller:

```
def index
  format.pdf render pdf: "index.pdf", template: "foos/index"
end
```

controller spec:

```
it "should render a pdf" do
  get :index, format: :pdf
end
```

feature spec:

```
scenario "User clicks PDF link" do
   click_link "PDF"
end
```

When I run either spec, it triggers a file download in OSX's Finder. I can't reasonably check this in and annoy my fellow dev's. Is there a way to prevent that?

A little more digging, and it's the `wkhtmltopdf` utility that causes a little program opening notification on the OSX dock.

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded my binary of `wkhtmltopdf` and it stops the notifications. https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/360